# Nested Tabs in Tabs in Tabs in Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the nested tab from Bootstrap 2.3.2 from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459912/nested-tabs-in-bootstrap).

But I want to use the newest Bootstrap Framework 3.3.6 or even 4.x Alpha, but I didn't changed any class names only the source of the CSS-,JS and the newer JQuery file.

My nested tabs should have not two tab orders but four.
You can see my current status at https://jsfiddle.net/ks93zdxk/3/

Questions:

1. I don't know, if I could/should change something from the Bootstrap 2.3.2 to Bootstrap  3.3.6 in this code.
2. If you click in "Passiv" in all combinations the the third order tabs should have the same position as the tabs from "Aktiv", which have the same names, but different IDs.
   I have the same problem with clicking on "transitiv (Hilfsverb avoir)". Here the second order tabs should have also the same position like on "intransitiv (Hilfsverb être)", which have also the same names, but different IDs.
   I think some `</div>`-tags had to be in other lines, but I don't know where  exactly they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principally, you did it right, but you've made some mistakes in the nesting of the HTML tags: the `<div class="tab-content">` needs to be wrapped around any group of `<div class="tab-pane">`.

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="etre-voice-gender1111">
    <p>Tab 1.1.1.1 être Aussage aktiv männlich</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="etre-voice-gender1112">
    <p>Tab 1.1.1.2 être Aussage aktiv weiblich</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example corrected](https://jsfiddle.net/k0mfyusa/1/).

You should consult the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Des salutations aus der Schweiz.

Comment: Thank you Fabian. Maybe you could help me with the script, too. We have a Chat about the Conjugation Script [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37043/french-conjugation).

Comment: In my cms the tab system only work in Google Chrome, if I add `async` to the bootstrap js-file. But it didn't work on Firefox or MS Edge, with or without `async`. I had included in my head first `bootstrap.min.css`, second `jquery.min.js` and before `</body>` the `bootstrap.min.js`.  I had used the CDN source for this three files.

Comment: `jQuery.ajax()` works on all modern browsers. You should move the JS library includes into the `<head>` section to ensure them to be ready in `<body>`. But to fix your problem, I need more details.

Comment: I have also tried to put `bootstrap.min.js` into the `<head>` section, but I didn't work. It worked on a test site, but I didn't use my "CMS" there. Maybe you could join the chat (Link in my first comment).

Comment: I found the mistake. I have to add `data-toggle="tab"` to the menu ulrs, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630595/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-not-working-for-me).