# Bootstrap 4 Pills with sub-pills

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav, nav-pills

The goal is to make pills in pills like that with bootstrap 4 pills or navs. So it has tree structure like each category has subcategories and them dynamic.

You can see structure here
[image]

And should looks like
[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-cvar-summary-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-summary" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-cvar-summary" aria-selected="true">Climate VaR Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-cvar-sector-analysis-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-sector-analysis" role="tab" aria-controls="#pills-cvar-sector-analysis" aria-selected="false">Sector Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-cvar-country-analysis-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-country-analysis" role="tab" aria-controls="#pills-cvar-country-analysis" aria-selected="false">Country Analysis</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-cvar-summary" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-cvar-summary-tab">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab-1" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-cvar-summary-primary-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-summary-primary" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-cvar-summary-primary" aria-selected="true">Primary Info & Allocation</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-cvar-summary-portfolio-analysis-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-summary-portfolio-analysis" role="tab" aria-controls="#pills-cvar-summary-portfolio-analysis" aria-selected="false">Portfolio Analysis</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-cvar-summary-spread-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-cvar-summary-spread" role="tab" aria-controls="#pills-cvar-summary-spread" aria-selected="false">spread</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tab-1Content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-cvar-summary-primary" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-cvar-summary-primary-tab">
        11111111
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-cvar-summary-portfolio-analysis" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-cvar-summary-portfolio-analysis-tab">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-cvar-summary-spread" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-cvar-summary-spread-tab">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? The example you've given doesn't seem to show any pills either, what exactly do you want them to look like?

Comment: @MTCoster Yeah it's just a mock. I will add code that I tried to one second

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459912/nested-tabs-in-bootstrap)?

Comment: Nope. For BS 4 no solution. See my answer guys. Now I made it work! Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with @Irin upgraded solution
1) use navs not button
2) Added content for the first section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Climate VaR Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Sector Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Country Analysis</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab-1" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab-1" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home-1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home-1" aria-selected="true">test 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-home-tab-2" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home-2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home-2" aria-selected="false">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-home-tab-3" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home-3" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home-3" aria-selected="false">test 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tab-1Content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-1">
        tabby 1
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="pills-home-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-2">
        tabby 2
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="pills-home-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-3">
        tabby 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Climate VaR Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Sector Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Country Analysis</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a working solution based on your post. But I need to upgrade your code, and now it works fine!

Comment: you are welcome. I just made a demo for you. please accept this as a accepted answer :)